# ASP.NET Javascript frameworks now

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, knockout.js

Im new in Web development and i try to improve as much as possible in ASP.NET MVC. Right now Im looking for good javascripts frameworks, that I can use in my projects and I found two options :

- angular - right now we waiting for version 2.0
- knockout

Already I know how to use jquery, bootstrap and materialize.

Could someone help me, which one framework should I choose to learn right now? Is knockout still worth learning or should I learn 1.x angular version and wait for 2 or maybe should i learn another javascript framework?
Thanks for every answer!

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but you can check out this site to get a comparison of the many frameworks out there: http://todomvc.com/

Comment: Too broad that is a personal opinion also depends on what you're using it for

Comment: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/choosing-javascript-framework

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search gave me this,

**Angular.js** is the front-runner of the JavaScript frameworks, and is one of the most popular JavaScript frameworks out there.
Angular.js was released in 2009 by Google, and no one would have guessed that it will become so popular in the near future. Angular.js gives the power in the hands of the programmer and lets them build single page web apps.

**Backbone.js** is minimalistic JavaScript frameworks that aim to provide the necessary backbone to a web application. The framework is open source in nature and is available under the MIT license.

**React.js** is one of the most popular front-end JavaScript framework.
Why Front-end? Becuase it can easily used to create the UI part of your project. In simple words, it acts as the V in MVC. The magic is achieved by using a virtual DOM and it can also be rendered on the server side with the help of the node.js.

**Knockout** is a MV (Model – View) Javascript Framework  which specializes in easy declarative bindings, automatic UI updation (on change in the model state) as well as powerful templating features. Knockout is built on pure Javascript, without any external dependencies. It also happens to work on most browsers.

there are many other great names in this list,
First of all It all depends on your project requirements to use any framework
but for learning purpose i would suggest starting from jquery
You  can start your learning from jquery and then you can extend it to Angular or Knockout these two are very much popular these days and are very helpful for developers.

Comment: He said, "Already I know how to use jquery". Also, jQuery is not a framework, it is the mess that frameworks help to solve.

Comment: Here by jquery i mean library , as I said it all depends on your project requirements Knockout and Angular js are just same thing , they are different by the way they solve the problem.Knockout is easier to start with since it has a very large community and have good documentation.Also Knockout supports almost all major browsers.